# Picker for Android app - Just like Android welcome screen

Tags: android

I've been looking around for a while now, I want to create a picker like the one in Android's welcome screen when starting it for the first time (see picture). E.g When scrolling between the different languages the title "Welcome" changes to match the word for the selected language. If you scroll to "Svenska" (Swedish) the title that says Welcome will change to "Välkommen" (Welcome in Swedish). How do I manage to do a picker like described?

Example:

[image]

Comment: just chaneg the text when the value changes...seems pretty easy to me

Comment: @tyczj But what should I do to make the "scroll wheel"?

Comment: Found a way now! Going to try it out right away

Comment: you scroll the wheel with your finger...

Comment: No shit? What I meant was.. "What is the best way to achieve this"? With a numberpicker?, custom spinner?, listview with a scroll effect?..and so on @tyczj

Comment: yeah just use a number picker with an array of strings